# Как исправить ошибку в php (function createQuery)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Всем здравствуйте, подскажите как исправить ошибку `Cannot redeclare createQuery()`, как я понял нельзя так две функции писать, скорее всего это грубейшая ошибка, помогите решить эту задачу..

```
                function createQuery($id, $a, $b){
                    $query = "INSERT INTO opisanie (x,text,text_opis) VALUES ";
                    $limit = count($a);
                    for($i=0; $i<$limit; $i++){
                        $query .= "('{$id}','{$a[$i]}', '{$b[$i]}')".($i!=$limit-1?',':'');
                    }
                    $res = mysql_query($query);
                }

                $aText = $_POST['form_text_o'];
                $aOpis = $_POST['form_text_opis'];

                $query = createQuery($id, $aText, $aOpis);



                function createQuery( $e, $s, $c, $d, $id){
                    $queryz = "INSERT INTO menu_zav (name,sostav,gramm,cena,x_zav) VALUES ";
                    $limita = count($e);
                    for($is=0; $is<$limita; $is++){
                        $queryz .= "('{$e[$is]}','{$s[$is]}','{$c[$is]}','{$d[$is]}','{$id}')".($is!=$limita-1?',':'');
                    }
                    $resa = mysql_query($queryz);
                }

                $eName = $_POST['form_name_menu'];
                $eOpisa = $_POST['form_opis_menu'];
                $eGr = $_POST['form_gr_menu'];
                $eCena = $_POST['form_cena_menu'];

                $queryz = createQuery($eName, $eOpisa, $eGr, $eCena, $id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как это *PHP*, а не *Java* или *C#*, к примеру, где можно писать одинаковые имена методов, но с разной сигнатурой (перегрузка методов), то единственным выходом является объявление метода с другим именем. Как его называть решать уже вам.

Только называйте осмысленно, а не `createQuery1` и `createQuery2`

Comment: точно, спасибо за ответ, теперь буду знать!

Comment: да ноу проблэмо.

Comment: А зачем осмысленно, если `createQuery1`  `createQuery2` варианты тоже работаю?

Comment: @harbor А потом вдруг будет createQuery3, createQuery4, createQuery5 и т.д.? А вы вспомните через год что это за квари такие и что они делают? А что возвращают? А если кто-то захочет поддерживать продукт ваш или начнет в коде разбираться? Ему что ж, надо в начале изучать ваше функции и методы вдоль и поперек, что б понять логику в месте вызова? Это же кошмар)) Ну и некультурно)

Answer (score 0):

Если принципиально использовать именно одноименную функцию, то могу предложить использовать **Аргументы переменной длины**. Так как версия PHP строго не определена, реализация будет отличаться. Проще всего вам будет обратится к документации [PHP](http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.arguments.php) для получения дополнительной информации.

В заключении хочется добавить, что это не самая лучшая идея.

Answer (score 0):

А почему Вы останавливаетесь на середине унификации? соберите все массивы в один двумерный (первая "строка" - имена полей, остальные - значения), и передавайте в функцию имя таблицы и этот массив. А список полей для вставки и блоки значений при формировании текста запроса собирайте implode-ом строки.